# convert selector of Swift 3.0 to 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

```
let selector: Selector = #selector(getter: UIPrinter.displayName)
```

i want to convert this line to swift 2.2

here is fullcode of function

```
func indexFiles() {

       let selector: Selector = #selector(getter: UIPrinter.displayName)
        sections = Array(repeating: [], count: collation.sectionTitles.count)



        if let sortedObjects = collation.sortedArrayFromArray(files, collationStringSelector: selector) as? [FBFile]{
            for object in sortedObjects {
                let sectionNumber = collation.sectionForObject(object, collationStringSelector: selector)
                sections[sectionNumber].append(object)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Referencing getter is Swift 3+ feature](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0064-property-selectors.md). So it maybe require some wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting selector from UIPrinter instance var. You can use

public init(_ str: String)  initializer of Selector class.

```
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "file url ")
    let printer = UIPrinter(URL:url)
    let selector:Selector = Selector(printer.displayName)
```